# Question about Ubuntu version 15.10

Tags: versions

Let's assume that I install Ubuntu / UbuntuMATE / UbuntuGNOME or any version 15.10. The support will be till july of 2016 as stated on some sites. 
This would mean that after that a new version will be relesed. 
After that will I be just able to upgrade to 16.x.x or something like that or will I be forced to reformat my computer and install that 16.x.x version?

Comment: "This would mean that after that a new version will be relesed" No, the new version is released months before the old one goes end of life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily upgrade to the next version when it is released, you absolutely do not have to reformat your partition.

**Note:** If it is not an LTS then, you **cannot** skip a version while upgrading, e.g.,

14.10: non-lts

15.04: non-lts

15.10: non-lts

The correct procedure to upgrade is (assuming you have 14.10):

```
14.10 > 15.04 > 15.10
```

Remember, you **cannot** upgrade from 14.10 directly to 15.10.

But, in case of LTS, e.g.,

14.04: lts

14.10: non-lts

15.04: non-lts

15.10: non-lts

16.04: lts (not released yet)

You **can** upgrade from 14.04 directly to 16.04.

Comment: But will they release next version before 15.10 expires?

Comment: Yes. Next version is 16.04 and will be released on April 2016.

Comment: Absolutely, as you can see in my answer, Ubuntu has a regular cycle every year that is one version in April YY.04 and one in October YY.10. YY - is the last two digits of that year.

Comment: So why then do people prefer LTS versions?

Comment: Its more stable and OLD :P, so less chances of error, supported widely by third party applications.

Comment: Is it bad for generaly use to use latest?

Comment: Not, so much but you might experience some glitches here and there(sometimes), also if you don't like self-repairing your PC (not very often)when you are unable to find any help online, then its better to stick to a lts

Comment: @MatjažJerman  well my customers do not want me to update a production server every 6 months...  They want to keep working. The time an LTS is alive is longer than the life of the hardware so that works better for a production server.

Comment: @Rinzwind - I absolutely agree.

Comment: I'll stick with using 15.10 because I mostly usit for browsing and programming for school :)

thanks for your answers.

Comment: @MatjažJerman - (y) :)

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 without loosing your files and programs. There is absolutely no need to reformat.

When the 16.04 update will be released, the update manager will simply prompt you if you want to install the new Ubuntu version or not.